# Java Scanner Class Fails with Multiple Uses

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I don't understand why this code works as I expect:

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan1, scan2;
        double weight = 0.0;

        scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a rational: ");
        try {
            weight = scan1.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("You entered " + weight);
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        }
        scan1.close();

        /*scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a rational: ");
        try {
            weight = scan2.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("You entered " + weight);
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        }
        scan2.close();*/
    }
}
```

and this code fails:

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan1, scan2;
        double weight = 0.0;

        scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a rational: ");
        try {
            weight = scan1.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("You entered " + weight);
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        }
        scan1.close();

        scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a rational: ");
        try {
            weight = scan2.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("You entered " + weight);
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Invalid data.");
        }
        scan2.close();
    }
}
```

(Note that the two versions are nearly identical. There is merely an uncommented block in the second.)

The output I get from the second version is:

```
Enter a rational: .97
You entered 0.97
Enter a rational: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at myPackage.ScanTest.main(ScanTest.java:28)
```

I don't understand why the Scanner object waits for input in the first block, but throws an Exception in the second. The behavior I would expect is:

```
Enter a rational: .97
You entered 0.97
Enter a rational: .43
You entered 0.43
```

The offending line 28 is:

weight = scan2.nextDouble();

I would appreciate anyone's insight into this behavior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the call to `scan1.close()` also closes `System.in` so that no more data can be read from the stream.  Check out the `close()` method description [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

So... by the time you start reading from `scan2`, `System.in` will no longer return any data.

Comment: And, with that, it's probably best if OP just closes the two scanners at the end of the gathering/display of input.

Comment: Ah, that must be it! System.in is being closed by the call to scan1.close(). Thank you, Mr. Lawry, and also PinkElephantsOnParade!